# Keycloak user resource - return user representation with roles and groups instead querying rest api for roles and groups

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I have to search users by text, groups and roles and it takes 6 seconds to query for users, groups and roles for each user, it is about 15 HTTP requests to Keycloak REST API.

Such slow searching is not acceptable from GUI point of view.. How u search users in your projects with Keycloak ? Do you synchronize users from Keycloak? Then data would not be fresh.. or maybe it is possible to write someadapter in Keycloak to synchronize data to my application, so the changes would be reflected immediatelly in my database and I would search users in my database. .? Or maybe uconnect to Keycloak data database ? But then u limit yourself to Keycloak version..

When serching users you get UserResources and u can do userResource.toRepresentation() to get specific data an you see groups and roles collections that are always empty.
Is it possible to retrieve UserResources that have groups and roles filled? Currently userResource.toRepresentation() returns user but with null groups and roles. So what groups and roles collections are for in UserRepresentation if they are always null?

Comment: I would say keycloak is not designed to do this kind of search. It is more of a identity management system than a search engine

Comment: is there any other server like keycloak for oauth2 autenthication, that is able to store users, their groups and can search fast via API ?

Comment: I am not aware of any such product

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly the topic but I needed to find the roles associated with a specific user and this question pops first with my keywords web search. Here's what worked for me with keycloak client 13.0.1

```java
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(REALM);
UsersResource usersResource = realmResource.users();
UserResource userResource =  usersResource.get(USER_ID);
RoleMappingResource roleMappingResource = userResource.roles();
// either realmLevel or clientLevel
RoleScopeResource roleScopeResource = roleMappingResource.realmLevel();
List<RoleRepresentation> rolesRepresentation = roleScopeResource.listAll();
```

I didn't find it elsewhere, I hope it can be useful.